# Amazon Product API - get list of books for multiple author names in one request

Tags: amazon-product-api

anybody knows if it is possible to get books for multiple authors in one request from Amazon Product API?

i'm using power search to query amazon but neither of these two power queries return any results:

author: (Dan Brown or Stephanie Meyers or J. K. Rowling) and pubdate: after 30-06-2006

author: Dan Brown and author: Stephanie Meyers and author: J. K. Rowling and pubdate: after 30-06-2006

query with a single name works fine.

is there something wrong with the query or is it just not possible?

Comment: umm, no :) we abandoned the project in the end

Answer (score 1):

You can try to send two individual requests at once using a *BatchRequest*
http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01/DG/index.html?BatchRequests.html

Comment: what if i want to check for example 2000 authors?